# Shopware 6 : why to add if condition if (module.hot) in src/Resources/app/storefront/src/main.js in custom plugins

Tags: shopware

While creating my own storefront JavaScript plugin in shopware 6.3.4.0 latest version, I'm trying to understand concept of following if condition.

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

Does anyone one what is the use of `module.hot` which is triggering `accept()` method call. Is it mandatory for storefront JavaScript plugin?

I was refereeing to [Shopware 6 Storefront JavaScript plugin](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/js-storefront-plugin) but there is no note of it.

Answer (score 1):

That is only used if you use `bin/watch-storefront.sh` for developing your plugin. That script starts an webpack npm "hot-proxy". With this you see your changes instant in your browser.
It is not mandatory. You can develop your plugin without this feature.
See https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/f464a9deb1ea93773cff6740df7d0ad09d37e5d1/src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/src/main.js#L94 for "reference".